# Trying to locate a sci-fi novel that I believe came out in the 1990s

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was a story about an astronaut that comes back to Earth to find all the people have gone.  Left behind are cities (that had moved underground) and some technology (like liquid nitrogen powered cars) and it appears that the people disappeared in a singularity in or related to Antarctica.

Sorry I don't recall much except maybe EARTH was in the title.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second book is "From a Changeling Star" by Jeffrey Carver (http://www.amazon.com/From-Changeling-Star-Jeffrey-Carver/dp/0759295956)

Answer (score 5):

I think this is "[Portal: A Dataspace Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_%28interactive_novel%29)"  by Rob Swigart. A copy in LRF format is currently available at the [MobileRead forums](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=37197)

The story, released in 1986 as an interactive fiction game, and in 1988 in book form, begins with the return of an astronaut from a failed mission to 61 Cygni, to find a park-like, depopulated Earth.

After wandering around for a while, he finds a barely functioning terminal with access to the global databases, which helps him to reconstruct the history of the last century or so.

Some of the points i remember are:

- All the cities were moved underground
- Some new technology allowed using environmentally clean cars, powered by liquid nitrogen
- Communication with dolphins
- At some point, there was an attack on research center based on Antarctica
- Humans dissapearing all around the world

Comment: @dvk - No worries.

Comment: Great!  That is it!!!!